# Count/Sum a column but exclude #N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently using the following forumlas to count the number of records in all of column Z that does not have #N/A but it does not work. All the rows in Column Z have a formula itself (Which is why some of them display #N/A, its a VLOOKUP).

```
=COUNTA(Z:Z)-SUM(IF(ISNA(Z:Z),1))
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TRIM(Z:Z)<>"#N/A"))
```

These return a "0" value which is not true, what am I doing incorrect?

[image]

Comment: Two things: your formula does _not_ appear to be an array formula (if it was it would be surrounded in `{}`) and its in column `Z` which you are trying to sum whole column, so it's a circular reference.  Put it somewhere else

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2010 or later, to count non-error values you can use (regular formula)

```
=AGGREGATE(3,6,Z:Z)
```

Answer (score 11):

No reason to use an array formula for this, you can just do something like

```
=COUNTIFS(Z:Z, "<>#N/A",Z:Z, "<>")
```

or

```
=COUNTA(Z:Z) - COUNTIF(Z:Z,"=#N/A")
```

The first one counts every nonblank, non #N/A cell. The second does what you're trying to do now and subtracts the total of #N/A cells from the total of every nonblank cell. Maybe using ISNA is technically more correct or faster, but this probably works just as well for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

This *array formula* sums the cells of range `Z:Z` that are not NA's :

```
=SUM(IF(NOT(ISNA(Z:Z)),Z:Z))  Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

This one (which is probably what you want) sums all but errors:

```
=SUM(IF(NOT(ISERROR(Z:Z)),Z:Z))  Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

And another (simpler) one

```
=SUM(IFERROR(H:H, 0))     Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you entering it as an array formula?  Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of just enter.  I think the first formula should work.

```
=COUNTA(Z:Z)-SUM(IF(ISNA(Z:Z),1))
```

Comment: yes, I am entering it as a array formula which is why I am so confused on the value of zero.

Comment: I'm stumped... what does it show you if you evaluate the formula?  Does Counta() return 0?

Comment: what do you mean by evaluate the formula? Yes, it returns zero. I edit my post with a screenshot.