# Count number of rows with values excluding #N/A or Null formula values from the count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My sheet1 has rows that have data updated by a formula. Some of the cells in the sheet have "#N/A" as values as the formula couldn't get the data. I am using COUNTIF and SUBPRODUCT to count the number of rows with values.

This works if rows in the range do not have #N/A values
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(LEN('Sheet1'!A2:A11)))
else it returns #N/A as the count

I have the same issue using =COUNTIF('Sheet1'!A1:A11,"?*"). It returns a 0 value.

[image: Table]

Appreciate any help.

But it returns a "N/A" value if one of the rows in the range has a "N/A".

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428105/count-sum-a-column-but-exclude-n-a) help?

Comment: I checked the link you provided prior to posting my question. My sheet2 is automatically updated when data is added to Sheet 3. Therefore the following works =SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN('Sheet2'!B:B)>0)) if rows have data copied from sheet 3. If any of the rows have #N/A values the same returns #N/A. Thank you for the help